# Does Microsoft Graph work without User.Read scope?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

My question is, does Microsoft Graph work without User.Read scope ? I am not able to request the email profile openid permissions directly.

It throws AccessDenied error. So is User.Read pre requisite for email profile or openid ?

Comment: I've post my ideas below and did I misunderstand in some place? Pls feel free to let us know if there's any further issue.

Answer (score 0):

`User.Read` is just the delegated permission for getting the user profile using [MS Graph Get User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). If your app does not need to read the user profile you don't need this permission but in most cases you do because you app is acting on behalf of the user.

**Does Microsoft Graph work without User.Read scope ?**

No, but in most cases, you need the scope to read user profile and call /me endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the **api document** to see if calling that api required `User.Read` permission.

For instance: I wanna call [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profile-list-emails?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions) to list emails, and we can see that this api provides 2 kinds of permissions, one is for delegate, another is for application(this means [client credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) flow is supported). All the api permissions are listed here and we need to go to azure ad portal to add the api permission to your azure ad application which used to generate access token.

[image]

After generating the access token, you can user jwt decode tool to check if your access token contains correct scopes(for delegate permission) or roles(for application permission). Using a correct token to call the api will not lead to `AccessDenied` error. By the way, newly added permission may be deferrable to take effect.